# How to receive result from listener(java)

Tags: java, android

Now I am making Android application, but I can not resolve by myself.

This application receives Json including location information from web application, parses it with GSON, and check its latitude and longitude.

Now the application can receive Json and parse it, but I don't know how to use the result of comparing.

```
public boolean checkArea(final LatLng latLng) {

    EventsClient client = new EventsClient();
    EventsClient.RequestObj requestObj = client.getRequestObj(
            Constants.SAMPLE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
            Constants.SAMPLE_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN
    );
    client.setListener(new BaseClientListener() {
        @Override
        public void returnValue(int errorCode) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "listener error:" + errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean returnValue(String result) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "listener result:" + result);

            Boolean insideCheck = false;

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<ResponseObj>>(){}.getType();
            List<ResponseObj> eventData = gson.fromJson(result, collectionType);

            for(ResponseObj responseObj : eventData){
                double eventLng = Double.valueOf(responseObj.getLongitude());
                double eventLat = Double.valueOf(responseObj.getLatitude());

                double eventLngRangeMax = eventLng + (500 / 30.8184 * 0.000277778);
                double eventLngRangeMin = eventLng - (500 / 30.8184 * 0.000277778);
                double eventLatRangeMax = eventLat + (500 / 25.2450 * 0.000277778);
                double eventLatRangeMin = eventLat - (500 / 25.2450 * 0.000277778);

                if (eventLatRangeMin < latLng.latitude && latLng.latitude < eventLatRangeMax && eventLngRangeMin < latLng.longitude && latLng.longitude < eventLngRangeMax) {
                    Log.d("chkArea", "inside area");
                    insideCheck = true;
                } else {
                    Log.d("chkArea", "outside area");
                    insideCheck = false;
                }

            }
        return insideCheck;
        }
    });
    client.getRequest(requestObj);
    // I want use "insideCheck" here!! <-----
}
```

The class calling `checkArea(final LatLng latLng)`:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

  if (checkArea(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))) {

      sendInformation(); //
  }
}
```

`BaseClientListener`:

```
public interface BaseClientListener {
    abstract public void returnValue(int errorCode);

    abstract public boolean returnValue(String result);

}
```

I am rookie and don't know the detail about the way to use "Listener",so It is too difficult for me. Please help me!

Comment: which is `listener` you are talking about?

Comment: Where are you calling `checkArea(final LatLng latLng)` from? You might want the class that you are calling `checkArea` from to implement your listener (`BaseClientListene`) interface or extend it if it's a concrete class. Then you will have the methods like `returnValue` implemented in your class.

Comment: I wrote about the class calling `checkArea (final LatLng latLng)` and `BaseClientListener`, Thanks.